How to transform or unpack *args types for typing variadics
I want to annotate a function that combines several iterators or generators into one, the case for two iterators is trivial:
def merge_two_iterators[T, H](
    gen1: Iterator[T],
    gen2: Iterator[H]
) -> Iterator[tuple[T, H]]: ...

But I can't make the arbitrary number of iterators work.
def merge_iterators[*Ts](
    *its: *Ts
) -> Iterator[tuple[*Ts]]: ... # wrong

How can I unpack the list of iterators into a tuple? Unpack is not doing the trick.
The result should be something like this:
a: list[int] = [1, 2]
b: list[str] = ['a', 'b']

c = merge_iterators(a, b)
# annotated as -> Iterator[tuple[int, str]]  or list[tuple[int, str]]

Solutions with old python versions <3.11 are accepted, solutions that don´t work in a specific typing tool such as mypy, but comply with the specs and preferably work in at least one tool are accepted as well.

Can you not use itertools.zip_longest?

What typing tool are you using? Mypy? Pyright? Please [edit] to clarify. (Or I may have misunderstood. I haven't gotten into the Python 3.12+ typing features yet.)

@OneCricketeer, is a minimal version of the problem, the real one can´t be solved by zip_longest.

@wjandrea 3.11 solutions will be accepted, I look for a solution that comply with the python specification, no matters if it fails for a specific typing tool (like mypy or pyright)  for instance mypy still has some issues with 3.12 syntax.

This is a commonly asked question, the most recent precedent being this one just over a month ago. Nothing has changed since then: still an impossible task.

As commented by @InSync this is not currently possible, but a ongoing topic:
https://discuss.python.org/t/pre-pep-considerations-and-feedback-type-transformations-on-variadic-generics/50605
However a workaround can be found in the built in implementation of zip:
https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/6a9b53e719a139c2d6b41cf265ed0990cf438192/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1763-L1801
By overloading as many cases as may be reasonable.
